# A word for a substitute

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, american-english

I need a word for: an item that can be substituted for another due to that item not being readily available...OR

what is the word for something that is used as a substitute while in a bind?

Comment: _Substitute_ seems to fit perfectly (or maybe _alternative_). Can you elaborate why the word you used yourself doesn't fit your purpose?

Answer (score 3):

The word you can use is: ***Substitute***

> Substitute (n) : a person or thing that takes the place or function of
>   another

Link for the same: [Meaning of substitute in Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substituted)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'd say "replacement"; however, I'm now intrigued by the word "bined" at the end of the query. I wonder if the asker meant "in a bind".
https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=in%20a%20bind

Comment: Yes, it's probably just a misspelling of *bind*. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Some synonyms for "substitute" that also express it is not the genuine item:

> Alternative
>   Surrogate (often used for persons)
>   Ersatz